# Following a relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a project dealing with bus routes and I’m using neo4j to retrive indirect routes between two stops. I modelled it in a way in which I was creating a ‘Route’ relationship for all the routes between two stops. This was okay at first but then I reached a point where I had at-least 10 relationships between any two given nodes and that led to most of the queries getting timed out.

So to reduce the number of relationships between two nodes, I am maintaining the routes between two stops as an array relationship property.

My question is how can I query the DB in such a way that I get that route which requires the lest number of bus changes. Can I implement something like backtracking to achieve this?

I have set up a neo4j instance with some dummy data. Here’s the link to it - http://207.154.231.108:7474/browser/

The query I’m using to find the shortest distance between two nodes.

```
  MATCH (origin:Stop {name: "Petraro"}), (destination:Stop {name: "Rossano Scalo - Torre Pisani"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((origin)-[:Route*]->(destination))
  RETURN path
```